# Apache Revese Proxy is not cached

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I have the below  config so all requests to /j/* will be proxied, however why not being cached as told ? 
Thanks

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/j/(.*)$" "http://192.168.1.121/$1" 
ProxyPassReverse "^/j/(.*)$" "http://192.168.1.121/$1" 
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public" 
CacheEnable disk / 
CacheEnable disk "http://192.168.1.121/" 
CacheRoot C:/project/Apache24/cache 
CacheDirLevels 2 
CacheDirLength 1 
CacheIgnoreCacheControl On 
CacheMaxFileSize 100000000 
CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On 
CacheMaxExpire 1209600 
CacheIgnoreQueryString On
```

Comment: this belongs on [sf]

Comment: can you move it or i delete/remake ?

Comment: request and response headers would be useful.